# How to disable Synaptics pinch-to-zoom support in evince (PDF viewer)?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, evince, synaptics, zooming

My friend experiences this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/875359
But most of the time zoom is activated unintentionally when using two-fingers scrolling on a Synaptics touchpad. Can I disable this zoom feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's as simple as `evince --disable-gestures`. But check your version to be 3.2.1-0ubuntu2+ :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/873866

If you want this to affect at opening files from file manager, you need to edit evince.desktop. Here is a one-line fix:
`$ sudo sed -i 's/^Exec=evince %U$/Exec=evince %U --disable-gestures/' /usr/share/applications/evince.desktop`

Comment: Is there a way to set evince to adopt this behavior whenever it runs? In other words, if I set evince as my default PDF reader, how can I make it disable gestures whenever it opens a file?

Comment: I think editing .desktop file will be enough. I will add sed command in a minute.